# git, "everything is up to date", how to overwrite remote?

Tags: git

I did the following;

I worked on a project which is in directory 'A'.
and My local git directory is some where also , let's say 'B'.

after finishing work on the project, I simply copied 'A' to 'B' and replaced 
files , just like mouse click copy-replace as we do.

then i try to to push changes to remote.

```
  git add *

  git commit -m "something"

  git push origin master
```

but did not work, it says "everything is up to date".
I used '-f' option but did not work.

I did not touch any '.git' in local git directory. I thought so should not be a problem.

so, how can I push changes to remote in this case?
Please be specific as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `git add .` instead and then run `git status` to see if any files have been added to this commit. Do you notice anything different?

Comment: What's the output of your `git status`?

Comment: Are you sure you are on the master branch?

Comment: Do you have the rights to push force on the master branch?

Comment: 'git status' outputs   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: yes, I have right to push, I created it.

Comment: maybe I should delete original project, then set up new one, then push to there.  avoid these pains

Comment: 1. did you actually verify that the files were really copied? 2. Maybe the files are ignored? 3. Are they untracked? Please post the output of `git status`

Comment: @eckes, I posted output of 'git status' above.  after struggling  and failing to push, I removed project and created new one and pushed there. my problem solved in that way. thanks everybody for trying to help me :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question then since OP doesn't provide any more details and the issue is no longer reproducable.